# Unity - Unit Test Tools (Missing Fields in Assertion Component)

Tags: unit-testing, unity-game-engine, assertion

I have some experience working in Unity, but never anything as complex as using the Unit Test Tools. I'm trying that now. However, my version is missing certain fields present (and necessary) from the Unity tutorials currently available. I have completely deleted Unity and reinstalled. I have had friends install the same version of Unity and the Unit Test Tools on their comparable machines, and they get the results seen in the tutorials. I have searched and searched, but found no mention of this issue. Please help.

Below are two screen shots. The first is the version in the tutorials (the one I am trying to get). The second is how my setup has it. It's specific to the assertion component.

**Desired Outcome**

[image: Desired Outcome]

**What I am getting**

[image: My unwanted version]